# Dictionary object type error

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I've updated my project to Swift 3 from 2.3 and I'm getting an interesting object error for dictionaries. I've tried rewriting this literal in a couple different ways to no luck and looked for answers but none so far posted for 3.0...

```
    let jsonRequest: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "requests": [
            "image": [
                "content": imageData
            ],
            "features": [
                [
                    "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
                    "maxResults": 10
                ],
                [
                    "type":"IMAGE_PROPERTIES",
                    "maxResults": 1
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Error displayed:

### "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal"

Can anyone explain to me what needs to be changed? Thanks!

Comment: Change AnyObject to Any.

Comment: haha thanks! simple fix is nice @matt

Comment: I feel a little dumb should have known that :P